# Speed up debugging in Javascript that use remote API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Lately I have been learning some Google Map API. I have this line of code:

`var paths = this.getPath;`

The correct line of code should be:

`var paths = this.getPath();`

I spent way too much time to figure it out. Pressing `Ctrl-Shift-J`, `try catch` in Javascript did not give me a clue.

Is there any tool that tells me that I am wrong when I'm working with a remote API so that I do not make the same kind of mistake in the future? My previous experience working with Java using IDE is much smoother thanks to the syntax error highlighting feature.

**Edit:** In short, how can I detect a mistake when writing the code, not in run time?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Typescript probably would have caught it.

Comment: @asawyer is right — [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial/) is designed specifically to allow what you're talking about (stop yourself from executing code in incorrect ways). However you would still have your problem because the Google Maps API is third party software not written in Typescript.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Chrome (I assume you are from your reference to `Ctrl-Shift-J`), you have an excellent Javascript debugger that allows you to add breakpoints, inspect variables, view the stack, step up and down the chain, etc.

When you realise you're not receiving the results you expected, the best policy is to set breakpoints on and after the calls to the Map API, and inspect the value of your variables before and after. This would reveal that `getPath` was a reference to a function and not a returned value.

As a general tip, properties prepended `get` tend to be functions. If it were a property, it would likely be `path` as opposed to `getPath`. The verb gives it away.

Comment: Are there any ways that I can detect a mistake when writing code, not in run time?

Comment: Depends on your environment. I use Sublime Text 2, which allows JSHint and JSLint integration. But these wouldn't catch your error — on the one hand you're using a dynamic 3rd party script, and on the other you're mis-using the API in an error-free way — assigning the `getPath` method to a variable named `path` isn't necessarily a mistake — only you can know what you're intending to do with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebStorm as an IDE. It provides excellent features as code completion, debugging, jslint/jshint,... The best IDE for javascript imho.

Combined with Chrome for testing it rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I think those kind of cases may be covered by your debugger as long as you've toggled the pause button at the bottom left corner to "Pause on all exceptions" (the light blue mode).

Comment: No, the debugger won't have a problem because nothing wrong is happening. There's nothing unusual about assigning a function to a variable without executing it, it's just author error.

Answer (score 0):

IE 10 developer tool's (Strangely the counterpart of Chrome, Firefox failed to notify me my errors, I am retesting this part) debugging can help me out. I will inform you more.